# Chrome Web Developer tools - how do I edit the CSS for a greyed out attribute?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

How do I edit the greyed-out attributes in this screenshot:

[image: CSS attributes greyed out]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just over-ride them by adding the individual properties or changing the "shorthand" to something like `padding: 10px 10px 0 0;` The 'top' property is what is in the actual CSS file.

The greyed-out ones are showing you the individual sub-properties that the shorthand applies.

Answer (score 0):

The greyed-out attributes are the ones your browser implicitly is calculating based on your property syntax,

referencing your example(if you want just padding-top) your syntax should be:

```
 padding: 10px 0 0 0;
```

[Check this out.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)